# how to check whether the app running on the on the first time from the main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i have checked my app is running for the first time or not , if the app is running for the first time , it should go to another activity called Intro, i have used the following code and it works fine

```
     SharedPreferences preferences=  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!preferences.getBoolean("Time",false))
    {


        Intent intent=new Intent("com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Intro");
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to Radio Planet ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Time",true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

My concern is when the user finishes the app introduction , it will go to my main activity or main screen , i want to do some stuff there also . how can i do that ?

Comment: write clear intentional word . you want to open a new Activity after intro or what you want to double check?

Comment: the above code will execute the intro activity when the app runs for the first time alright. after finishes the intro , how to check whether the app is running for the first time or not, from the main activity?. because i want show another thing from the main activity after finishes the intro @AvinashAjayPandey

Comment: i have added the code for you check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay . the same thing you have to write in mainActivity again and check with the same tag field .
 i'm going to explain you the shared preference .

create this class as a external class .

```
public class SessionManager {

    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "PREF_NAME";

    private static final String KEY_IS_FIRSTTIME = "Time";


    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void setFirst(boolean isFirst) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRSTTIME, isFirst);
        editor.commit();    // commit changes
        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean getFirst() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRSTTIME, false);

    }

}
```

then write the code in your intro Activity

---

```
 if (new SessionManager(this).getFirst)
    {

       //write code not a first time

      }else{
        Intent intent=new Intent("com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Intro");
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to Radio Planet ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new SessionManager(this).setFirst(true);
    }
 with the same code you can check in mainActivity that it's first time or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `editor.putBoolean("Time",true);` from the starter activity and check for it in the main activity after you check it set its value to true

Comment: I didn't get your question but now you will check the preference value two times in the intro activity and in the main activity but you will set its value to true in the main activity not the intro

Comment: ok remove  ( editor.putBoolean("Time",true); )  from it and use the same code again in the activity where you want to check for first time again but in this activity add ( editor.putBoolean("Time",true); ) after you make the check